# spring data mongodb MongoRepository.save(T entity) method not working?

Tags: spring, mongodb

The code is listed below:

```
 @Document
  @XmlRootElement
  public class User {

        @Indexed(unique=true)
    private String username;

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String password;
       ...... omit setters and getters
     }
public interface UserRepo extends MongoRepository<User, String>{

}

public User update(User user) {
    User existingUser = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    if (existingUser == null) {
        return null;
    }

    existingUser.setFirstName(user.getFirstName());
    existingUser.setLastName(user.getLastName());


    return userRepo.save(existingUser);
}
```

when update method invoked, the finds the user based on username and finishes without any exceptions, the returned User obj has all updated value but the underlying mongodb document is not changed! Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need an Id field with @Id annotation